# Data from TLF TextLine

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

i have some problem with utilizing TLF, i need to parse through the text and get x and y for each character inside the textfield. This is what i have so far...

Getting every TextLine from the TextFlow:

```
if (textflow.flowComposer) {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < textflow.flowComposer.numLines; i++) {
         var flowLine:TextFlowLine = textflow.flowComposer.findLineAtPosition(i);
         var textLine:TextLine = flowLine.getTextLine(true);
    }
}
```

Getting every "atom" for the TextLine:

```
var charPosition:int = textLine.textBlockBeginIndex;
while (charPosition < textLine.textBlockBeginIndex + textLine.rawTextLength) {
    var atomIndex:int = textLine.getAtomIndexAtCharIndex(charPosition);
    textLine.getAtomBounds(atomIndex);
    charPosition = textLine.getAtomTextBlockEndIndex(atomIndex);
}
```

This works for getting the bounding for each character but i still need some more data like what character is it and what font-size, font does it have? When doing a textLine.dump(); i think im getting this data but not the character, i get something called gid witch seems to point to the character in use but i don't know how to get exactly what character that is. Anny ideas?

Comment: I guess on third line should be `getLineAt(i)` instead of `findLineAtPosition(i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with the help of Jin-Huang over at the [adobe forum for TLF](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3726304#3726304). I haven't tried it to full extent yet, but seems to work for now.